# Enzyme shallow() and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have this component, which works fine in the application:

```
class TheComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchForClicks();
  }

  watchForClicks() {
    this.elementRef.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('there went one!');
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={theElement => {
          this.elementRef = theElement;
        }}
      >
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TheComponent;
```

And this test:

```
describe('<TheComponent />', () => {
  context('do a test:', function() {
    it.only('fails!', () => {
      wrapper = shallow(<TheElement />)
    })
  });
});
```

Why do I get this error?

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.elementRef.addEventListener')
```

Comment: Why are you using ref and adding eventlistener for clicking on react? why not just do `<div onClick={() => console.log('there went one!')}>`? And then on enzyme you can do `wrapper.prop('onClick')()`

Comment: The above is a simplified version of the actual component. I need it for reasons that are outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html), the ShallowWrapper API doesn't have a `ref()` method, but you can use [`mount()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) instead, which [does have the `ref()` method](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#refrefname--reactwrapper).